# Add Ingress to k8s cluster running on Docker for external management from Rancher

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an EKS Anywhere running on Docker (on en EC2 instance) and need to manage it externally from Rancher or Rancher Desktop. It's not clear to me how to configure Ingress to the public IP of the EC2 node. Any advise appreciated. Let's assume the public IP of the instance is 100.101.102.103/32

I see a package called Imissary which might do this but still the nut sand bolts are still unclear.
eksctl anywhere generate package emissary --cluster  > emissary.yaml

root@ip-10-0-31-149:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
dd10009c5283   public.ecr.aws/eks-anywhere/kubernetes-sigs/kind/node:v1.27.4-eks-d-1-27-10-eks-a-49   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   22 hours ago   Up 21 minutes             mgmt-md-0-679dc5f899xhn4c9-x5j6w
9e5c0ae37871   public.ecr.aws/eks-anywhere/kubernetes-sigs/kind/node:v1.27.4-eks-d-1-27-10-eks-a-49   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   22 hours ago   Up 21 minutes             mgmt-etcd-tn89k

kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://127.0.0.1:32768
CoreDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:32768/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

kubectl get svc
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
hello-eks-a   NodePort    10.109.83.149           80:30965/TCP   102s
kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1               443/TCP        15m